# SNMP-библиотека для Python

Tags: python, snmp

Кто как считает: какая из библиотек, реализующая поддержку данного протокола наиболее удачна? Погуглив, я нашел только две:

1. pysnmp
2. twistedSNMP

Но что-то ни одна мне не приглянулась, ввиду их громоздкости :(. 
Не подскажете, что-нибудь полегче, на подобие перловой NET::Snmp?

Answer (score 2):

Net-SNMP имеет [привязки](https://net-snmp.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/net-snmp/trunk/net-snmp/python/README) для Python. Поэтому если есть желание использовать что-то, похожее на Net-SNMP, надо именно его и использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Я тут высказал своё мнение несколько по другому вопросу, но в ответе сравниваю несколько библиотек. Может быть - пригодится:

[NetSNMP - прочитать float](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862476/netsnmp-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-float/865857#865857)