# NetSNMP - прочитать float

Tags: python, python-3.5, snmp

Читаю целые переменные из агента приблизительно так:

```
ss = netsnmp.Session(Version=2, DestHost=ip, Community='public')
oid = '...'
vb = netsnmp.Varbind(oid, '0')
vl = netsnmp.VarList(vb)
int_val = ss.get(vl)
```

Результат запроса преобразую к целому типу:

```
return  int(int_val[0])
```

Всё работает нормально. Попытался сделать аналогично для *float*:

```
ss = netsnmp.Session(Version=2, DestHost=ip, Community='public')
oid = '...'
vb = netsnmp.Varbind(oid, '0',None,'OPAQUE')
vl = netsnmp.VarList(vb)
float_val = ss.get(vl)
```

И затем преобразовать:

```
float(float_val[0])
```

Однако так не проходит! Выдаётся ошибка:

```
translate_asn_type: unhandled asn type (120)
```

И при попытке преобразовать пустое значение, программа ломается:

```
float(float_val[0])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Вопрос: как правильно читать/писать плавающие значения?

- Linux Ubuntu 16.04
- Python 3.5
- NetSNMP - последняя с сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что мой опыт - "сын ошибок трудных" может ещё кому-то пригодиться. Так что отвечаю сам себе.

Я перепробовал пять Python библиотек для работы с SNMP:

- netsnmp
- pysnmp
- libsnmp
- netsnmp-py
- EasySNMP

Только одна из них *pysnmp* не падала, при попытки прочитать значение типа *float*. Однако, возвращаемое значение имело вид не очень приглядный: строка (!!!) '0x9f780441703344'.

Я быстро понял, что это  ни что иное, как TLV структура:

- T=9F78
- L=04
- V=41703344

С типом так: 9f - признак сложного типа с кодом более 31. 78 - это 16-ричная запись кода 120, на которую ругались библиотеки.

Ну, с длиной всё ясно - 4 байта плавающего слова.

А вот с самим значением пришлось повозиться. В конце концов преобразовал его так:

power = (snmp_get_next(community, ip_address, port_snmp, OID_power))
bar = bytes.fromhex(power[8:])
print('Power = ', struct.unpack('>f', bar ) )

Т.е. я достал из СТРОКИ все байты, начиная с 8-го и преобразовал их из символьного 16-ричного представления в 4 байта, байты распаковал как число с плавающей точкой в big-endian формате.

После этого я более внимательно посмотрел на библиотеку PySNMP. Библиотека имеет следующие особенности:

1. Полностью написана на Python. Никакие so-шки или dll-ки ей не нужны.
2. Имеет великолепную документацию
3. Имеет API высокого уровня, позволяющее делать сложные вещи за пару строк
4. Полностью поддерживает V3 SNMP.

Короче, **моё** мнение - это лучшая библиотека.